# Active directory listing groups - LdapConnection works, PrincipalContext does not

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Creating a web service which talks to Active Directory to verify users and determine which groups they belong to.

I started out with the verification process, and got this working:

```
    public bool AuthenticateAdUser(string username, string password)
    {
        //in the real code, these come from config
        string domain = "TestDomain";
        string server = 666.666.666.666;
        string authType = "Basic";
        string useSsl = "false";

            AuthType atype = (AuthType)Enum.Parse(typeof(AuthType), authType);

            using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(server))
            {
                var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
                ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = Convert.ToBoolean(useSsl);
                ldapConnection.AutoBind = false;
                ldapConnection.AuthType = atype;
                ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
            }

            // If the bind succeeds, the credentials are valid
            return true;
    }
```

However, I'm not clear on how I can use that LdapConnection object to work with groups. The documentation and examples suggest you use PrinicpalContext for that purpose. So I tried this.

```
        string domain = "TestDomain";

            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username).GetGroups(pc))
                {
                    src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
                }
            }
```

This fails, claiming it can't contact the Active Directory server. Using a DNS style name ("TestDomain.local") doesn't seem to help.

This does at least spin up a network principal:

```
        string server = "666.666.666.666";

            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, server))
            {
                using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username).GetGroups(pc))
                {
                    src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
                }
            }
```

But when you try and do anything with it, it fails with "Network path not found".

Any ideas on why the Principal won't work, or how I can use the LdapConnection to query groups?

Comment: Is the computer you are running your program on joined to your test domain?

Comment: No. But it should have access to it. This software is eventually supposed to facilitate communication between different domains.

Comment: If I try your code from a non domain joined computer I get the same exception. The stack trace says that one of the internal Account Management classes can't determine the domain controller. If I the code from a domain joined computer everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for checking that out - it at least saves me wasting time trying the wrong solution. Will falls back on DirectoryServices instead. If you post that comment as an answer, I'll tick it.